# Django admin include model pk in push notification

Tags: django, push-notification

I'm trying to send a push notification of an article with its id.pk value from django admin form.
I've searched on how to get id.pk from admin.py I've also added the below to the model but I can't seem to get the value from admin.

Here is my model.

```
class Notice(models.Model, HitCountMixin):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='제목')
    category = models.CharField(choices=NOTICE_CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=18, verbose_name='분류', default='뉴스')
```

I can see this in the list but not from the django admin edit form. I need the id in order send within json data the push notification. Is there way to make this happen.
admin.py

```
readonly_field = ('id' , 'file_link')

    def save_model(self, request, instance, form, change):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        print(form.cleaned_data.get('category'))
        print(form.cleaned_data)

        # PUSH
        # ------------------------------------------------------------------
        if(form.cleaned_data.get('is_push')):
            title = form.cleaned_data.get('title')
            body = form.cleaned_data.get('content')
            message = strip_tags(body)[:100] 
            try:
                job = django_rq.get_queue('default', default_timeout=3000)  
                job = django_rq.enqueue(send_to_all, title, message, extra)
            except:
                pass
        # ------------------------------------------------------------------

        form.save()
```

Things I've tried or considered :

- Set id as integer to autoincrement
- Send id value as hidden from admin list to detail. But I can't find the location to pass this to fieldset.html.

Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Can you save the instance first and then send the push notification? Typically a model's id is generated by the database on save so it's not possible to reliably predict what id an unsaved instance will get.

Comment: I've considered this too, then is there a way/method to save the instance and then send that model id to the daemon to send the push?

Comment: Thanks azundo, based on your suggestion I've created a work around to send the push notification with django actions. When the user makes a make_published action I can send the item pk and its contents through push notification. Wished there was a way to send and auto push at the same time though...